# XCode 8: Views not adjusting when UIElement is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am trying to conditionally make a UILabel at the bottom of my view controller hidden and the view immediately above that adjust to fill the space.

The UILabel at the bottom of the view controller has a height of 120 and a constraint to the bottom of the view controller of 0. The view above it has a constraint to the bottom of the view controller of 120.

When I make the UILabel hidden and change the value of the view above it to the the bottom of the view controller to 0 (named viewBottomConstraint), the UILabel disappears but the view above it remains where it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the label to hidden, just change the height constraint!
You see setting the property to hidden has no effect on the nearby views but changing the height to 0 and calling `layoutIfNeeded`, updates all the constraints related to that particular `UILabel` and lays out all the views.

You need to set the height constraint to 0 of the `UILabel`. Do this by dragging an outlet of the height constraint from your storyboard to your `UIViewController` and then just:

```
heightConstraint.constant = 0.0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```